# Validate list contents

Tags: python, list, validation, input

Suppose that I create a list by casting input to list:

`Lst = list(input())`

How can I make a loop so that the input from the user contains only R B or G

For example, if the input is Rbrg, the loop should continue until input containing only `R`, `B` or `G` is introduced (no spaces)

Using regex, the pattern is :
`pat = re.compile("[RBG]")`

```
for each in Lst:
    while True:
        if not re.match(pat, each):
            Lst = list(input())
        else:break
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: `Lst = list(input())`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. I've made the check case insensitive.

```
while True:

    user_input = input('enter strings: ')

    if set(map(str.lower, user_input)) <= set('rbg'):

        print(user_input)

        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, you can use a generator comprehension with the function `all`:

```
while True:
   user_input = input('enter string: ')
   if all(i in 'RGB' for i in user_input):
      do_something(user_input)
      break
```

Comment: This seems pretty neat. Thanks!